# simplify jquery parents and childrens

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to get a far parent's child's child's attribute href...

now i can get that using this long statement

```
var uid = $(this).parents(':eq(7)').children( ).find('.p_cell')
.children(':eq(0)').children(':eq(0)').attr('href');
```

please any string using '>' and ' : ' that can simplify the statement

thanks

Pradyut

India

Comment: give to child element unique id , its simplify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Without* knowing the HTML, you can use [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) like this:

```
var uid = $(this).parents(':eq(7)')
                 .find('> * .p_cell > :first-child > :first-child').attr('href');
```

If that parent has a class you can access though, instead of say the 8th parent  you could find it via a selector that matched using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).  For example if that parent was a `<div>` like this:

```
<div class="container">
```

You could do this:

```
var uid = $(this).closest('.container')
                 .find('> .p_cell > :first-child > :first-child').attr('href');
```

However, if you posted the HTML this can likely get much simpler.